# Primary key using a predefined format in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key, rdbms

I am trying to create a table that will generate a primary key automatically using a predefined format. Like this:

```
Customer_ID    Name   Phone
cust_1         Abc    123
cust_2         Def    456
```

Here Customer_ID is auto generated primary key.

Comment: Presumably the database is Oracle.  SQLPlus is just an interactive tool.

Answer (score 1):

typically you just generate the number and the rest of the fluff (CUST_ in your case) is presentation.

If it's really important you can have a computed column that adds on the prefix - just make sure you put indexes and unique constraints where they need to be.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a computed column?

Comment: Yes you can do it with a trigger or store proc (or where ever it is you assign the sequence to the Customer_ID column) but my point stands - the additional decoration does not add anything at all.  It's just presentation and I'd personally ignore it until you need to show it somewhere.

Comment: duly noted, but I have to assign the prefix for different people in the table, cust_ for those who are customers. Hence the annoyance.

Comment: *"cust_ for those who are customers"*: Oh, *that* decision is *really* going to hurt someday.

Comment: Agreed @Mike Sherrill.  ID is the ID.  krthkskmr - You should be using another column to indicate the purpose of the entity, not hacking around with the ID.